# downgrade sklearn 0.22.3 to 0.22.2 in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, prompt

When I run in jupyter file

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

The result is 0.23.2
However I would like to install 0.22.2. Therefore I put into prompt

```
conda remove scikit-learn
```

and install:

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.22.2
```

unfortunately there is this error:

```
 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: scikit-learn=0.22.2
```

How can I delete sklearn version 0.23.2 and install 0.22.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding the `conda-forge` channel to your list of channels when you search for packages.

This should work:

> RUN
>
> ```
> conda config --append channels conda-forge
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> conda install scikit-learn=0.22.2
> ```

OR

> RUN
>
> ```
> conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn=0.22.2
> ```
>
> instead of 2 above commands